# Double vs. single quotes using formatted printing in python

Tags: python, string, output

So I was going through "Learn Python the Hard Way"

and while doing this:

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"

print formatter % (
    "I had this thing.",
    "That you could up right.",
    "But it didn't sing.",
    "So I said goodnight"
)
```

the output was

```
'I had this thing.' 'That you could up right.' "But it didn't sing." 'So I said goodnight'
```

But I'm not sure why the 3rd string has double strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"a"` and `'a'` are the same strings, no difference.

The third string contains an apostrophe, so it cannot be represented as `'But it didn't sing.'` because that would end the string after `didn` and raise a `SyntaxError`.

If you want to represent a string with single quote, you can do it:

```
"'"
```

or

```
'\''
```

The same with double quote:

```
'"'
```

or

```
"\""
```

If you have a string with both quotes, you can choose one:

```
'"\'"
```

or

```
"\"'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the third string would be `'But it didn't sing'` - this would provide a syntax error due to three apostrophes, and furthermore, if fixed logically(putting one more ' in the end which would remove the error), you'd be stuck with two strings - 1. `'But it didn'` and 2. `'t sing'`, which is not correct.

So to answer your question, "" provide the exact same function in strings but is used when a syntax error could be caused, such as for words like didn't, couldn't, or the like in the English language.

Comment: FWIW, `'But it didn''t sing'` _is_ valid syntax but it doesn't do what we want because Python treats adjacent string literals as a single string. This also happens if there's whitespace between the string literals.

Answer (score 1):

The third string has a `'` character in it, that's why `"` is used to represent it. Try removing the `'` from string #3 and you'll see the representation change to `'`string`'`. The strings are identical, it's just a difference in their representation.